# Laravel Eager loading collection of specified column in one to many relationship

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Is that possible to do these actions in one query?

```
$detail = Goods::find(1);
$detail->pictures = $detail->pictures()->lists('link');
// output
[
  'id' => 1,
  'name' => 'IPhone',
  'pictures' => [
    0 => 'http://whatever.com/1.jpg',
    1 => 'http://whatever.com/2.jpg',
   ],
]
```

I had tried this

```
Goods::with(['pictures' => function($query){
    $query->select('link');
}])->find($id);
```

no expected output

Answer (score 0):

You need to also select foreign key. And you can use `toArray()` to convert collection into an array:

```
Goods::with(['pictures' => function($query){
    $query->select('link', 'good_id');
}])->find($id)->toArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

With your above query, how would you know which `Good` belongs to which `Picture` without the keys? Eloquent doesn't know it either, so it can't match related models.

This is what you need:

```
$good = Goods::with(['pictures' => function($query){
           $query->select('id', 'good_id', 'link');
        }])
        ->find($id);
```

Then you can use collection's `pluck` method as:

```
$good->pictures = $good->pictures->pluck('link');
```